# получение значения с поля input

Tags: javascript, django

Что нужно сделать, чтобы код, приведенный ниже, работал на форме моего сайте с использованием `djangо`

```js
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.txt').html(val);
  $('.txt').val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="pole" placeholder="type here">
<p class="txt"></p>
```

вот форма

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
   <div class="txtb">{{form.date.label}} {{form.date}}</div>
   <div class="txtb"> <p class="txt"></p></div>
<input type="submit" value="{%trans 'Отправить' %}" class="btn" id="btn"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
<div class="txtb date-input">{{form.date.label}} {{form.date}}</div>


$('.date-input').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.txt').html(val);
  $('.txt').val(val);
});
```